# MSBuild Task to read version of dll

Tags: msbuild

I am looking for a MSBuild task that will tell me the version of a specific dll.  Is there a task available for this?

In my case the dll is a .Net assembly, so I'm actually looking for Assembly.FullName.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks madgnome!  I thought I would share the working code.

```
<Target Name="UpdateWebConfigVersion">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="lib\foo.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="fooAssemblyInfo"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="src\Web\ServiceModel.Extensions.config"
            XPath="//extensions/behaviorExtensions/add[@name='silverlightFaults']/@type"
            Value="foo.ServiceModel.Extensions.Behaviors.SilverlightFaultBehavior, foo, Version=%(fooAssemblyInfo.Version), Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXX"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: I make zip files in my build script, this helped me put the version number in the filename!!!  Thanks!

Comment: the working code example really help - a big time saver.  Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

[GetAssemblyIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx) is your man. This task outputs contain item metadata entries named Version, PublicKeyToken, and Culture.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyAssemblies Include="File1.dll;File2.dll" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="RetrieveIdentities>
    <GetAssemblyIdentity
        AssemblyFiles="@(MyAssemblies)">
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Assemblies"
            ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
</Target>
```