# How to set the version of a project in VS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I want to be able to use the **AssemblyIdentities.Version** in my msbuild, how do I set/change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click `Project`->`Properties`->`Assembly Information` or (when have already created the properties) in project manager `Properties`->`AssemblyInfo.cs`.

**Edit**: For auto-modification from msbuild, you can use:

```
<FileUpdate Files="AssemblyInfo.cs"
   Regex="(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"
   ReplacementText="$1.$2.$3.$(Revision)" />
```

Comment: I think IAdapter is looking to set the version in an msbuild invocation

Comment: @David: Thanks, I have missed it at the first glance. Although it's pretty much the same as modding it manually.
@IAdapter: You can auto-generate the whole AssemblyInfo.cs if you want ;)

Comment: There is one more thing you should take in attention. Third component of the version is usually used to change current version of assembly/product/... Forth component can be used as a marker of internal build number, or as a way to provide updates for old assembly without version conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You do it with the [GetAssemblyIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx) task:

```
<Target Name="Version">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity
      AssemblyFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\MyApp\bin\MyApp.exe">
  <Output
      TaskParameter="Assemblies"
      ItemName="AssemblyIdentities"/>
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  ...
</Target>
```

`AssemblyIdentities` is just a variable name. It could also be named `MyAssemblyIdentities` like in the MSDN link. The `Version` property reads the Version from your `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443188/msbuild-task-to-read-version-of-dll) SO answer provides some examples on how to use `GetAssemblyIdentity`.