# I would like to have my AssemblyVersion in my deployment package name

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration

I am using MSbuild to create a deployment package (simply copying various files from the projects in my solution to different folders) I would like the root folder to be of the format

DeploymentPackage2.3.4.5ForRelease

How can I get MSbuild to put the Assembly number in the folder name automatically?

EDIT:
The solution has a great deal of projects in it (too many really) they all get their version number from a SharedAssemblyInfo.cs file that is manually updated but in the fullness of time will pick up the svn build number (but that is a job for later) 
I am building using an external .bat file that calls a custom written .targets/.proj setup that simply calls msbuild on the .sln of the solution. 
The 'create package' step I am trying to create happens after a succesful build and will eventually be run by our CI framework, however I would like to be able to run it locally too.

I have created a "CreatePackage" target that does the copying that I want, however it is currently into a fixed folder. I need the folder name to reflect the AssemblyVersion of one of the final dll's.

Comment: would you like this to be a post-build event to standard compilation?  Do you have more than one assembly?  have you done any other MSbuild customization to rev your AssemblyVersions on multiple files synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a better way then I want to know about it... but I am going to use this I think

[MSBuild Task to read version of dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443188/msbuild-task-to-read-version-of-dll)