# Access Version from AssemblyInfo in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package, assemblyinfo

I am trying to create/push nuget package through visual studio build process as explained [here](http://ihadthisideaonce.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/creating-packages-with-nuget-the-msbuild-way/).

Building package is easy:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="$(NuGetApp) pack $(ProjectFile) -OutputDirectory $(Deploy) -Verbose -Prop Configuration=Release"/>
```

I see .nupkg file in $(Deploy) folder.

But to be able to push it, I need $(AssemblyVersion) to use it in :

```
<Exec Command="$(NuGetApp) push $(ProjectName)$(AssemblyVersion) -s $(NugetServer) $(NugetKey)" />
```

I tried XMLRead to fetch the value, but value in NugetSpecFile is "$version$" instead of version from AssemblyInfo.cs.

```
<XmlRead XPath="/package/metadata/version" XmlFileName="$(NuSpecFile)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </XmlRead>
```

How do I access version so I could use it in "nuget push"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This i'll do it:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyAssemblies>somedll\the.dll</MyAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="RetrieveIdentities">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity
        AssemblyFiles="$(MyAssemblies)">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Assemblies"
          ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>

    <Message Text="Files: %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)"/>
  </Target>
```

Altered from here:
[MSBuild Task to read version of dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443188/msbuild-task-to-read-version-of-dll)