# Append version name to output directory on publish

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm using the publish to file-system option in Visual Studio, and I'd like the publish process to automatically append the assembly version-number to the output directory when I publish a project.

Google just isn't getting me the answer.

Is this possible?  How-to?

Comment: Have a look at this:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c60d33ad-6196-4f02-9dc6-9ed5179672df/specifying-version-and-publish-location-in-msbuild-targetpublish?forum=winformssetup also have u tried msbuild community task? I have pretty sure there is something you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get the assembly version as described in the following posts:

[MSBuild Task to read version of dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443188/msbuild-task-to-read-version-of-dll)

[Access Version from AssemblyInfo in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709677/access-version-from-assemblyinfo-in-msbuild)

As follows[Altered version of the code as described in the given links]:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
     <AssemblyList>myfolder\myLibrary.dll</AssemblyList>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="AssemblyInformations">
   <GetAssemblyIdentity
    AssemblyFiles="$(AssemblyList)">
  <Output
      TaskParameter="Assemblies"
      ItemName="AssemblyInfos"/>
</GetAssemblyIdentity>

<Message Text="Files: %(AssemblyInfos.Version)"/>
```

And then I would use something like the following to create a directory in the place you want to publish:

```
    <CreateProperty Value="$(Public_Shared_Folder)$(ProjectName)\">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="PublicFolderToDropZip" />
</CreateProperty>
<MakeDir Directories="$(PublicFolderToDropZip)" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Release' And !Exists('$(PublicFolderToDropZip)')" />
```

The entire operation can be completely automated.